$\lim_{n\to \infty} \cos\frac{\pi}{2^2}\cos\frac{\pi}{2^3}\dots\cos\frac{\pi}{2^{n-1}}\cos\frac{\pi}{2^n}$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \cos\frac{\pi}{2^2}\cos\frac{\pi}{2^3}\dots\cos\frac{\pi}{2^{n-1}}\cos\frac{\pi}{2^n}$$
This was taken from UGM Maths Competition that was brought in teacher forum few days ago that we hadn't got time to solve. I was wondering about the question as I see the problem as two possible questions.
The first one is:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^2}\cos\frac{\pi}{2^3}\dots\cos\frac{\pi}{2^{n-1}}\cos\frac{\pi}{2^n}\right)$$
Or could be this one:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^3}\right)\dots\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n-1}}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^n}\right)$$
Whatsoever which one it is, the given multiple-choice is:
A. $0$
B. $\pi$
C. $\frac{\pi}2$
D. $\frac{2}{\pi}$
E. $\frac{4}{\pi}$
I know it's ambiguous, sorry. Since I dare not calculate the first one, as I've no idea (lol), I would assume it was the second one... I start to think that
$$\sin(2x) = 2\sin(x)\cos(x)$$
And if I substitute $y=2x$
$$\sin(2y) = 2\sin(y)\cos(y)$$
Which is
$$\sin(4x) = 2\cdot 2\sin(x)\cos(x)\cos(2x)$$
I got the pattern, and I believe if I keep going, I'd end up with
$$\sin(2^n x) = 2^n\sin(x)\cos(2^0x)\cos(2^1x)\dots\cos(2^{n-2}x)\cos(2^{n-1}x)$$
Since the $\lim$ depends on $x$ and we don't have it there, I believe it was just what in the inside of the limit. Simplificating it would give me
$$\dfrac{1}{2^{n-1}\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2^n}\right)}$$
I hope I didn't miss anything. I'm stuck at there. Could you help me please? T.I.A.!

It's the second interpretation; writing $\cos a \cos b$ means $(\cos a)(\cos b)$. If you wanted the other interpretation, it's $\cos(a \cos b)$. Also, presumably these limits are $\lim_{n \to \infty}$, not $\lim_{x \to \infty}$?

How about small angle approximation in the last step?

I have verified the question by checking it again and it was $\lim_{x \to \infty}$, or was it mistyped? Sorry I've no idea. Will it have a solution in the multiple-choice if I write $\lim_{n \to \infty}$?

Notice that :
$$\dfrac{1}{2^{n - 1} \sin \frac{\pi}{2^n}} = \dfrac{2}{\pi} \dfrac{\dfrac{\pi}{2^n}}{ \sin \dfrac{\pi}{2^n}}$$ and $$\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{h}{\sin h} = 1$$

Yes, thanks you. I eddit it

It is well known. See also on Wikipedia: Vieta's formula

To start with, notice the following relation holds when $n\to\infty$
\begin{align*}
\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n}}\right) \sim \frac{\pi}{2^{n}}
\end{align*}
Consequently, it may be claimed that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}2^{n - 1}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n}}\right) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(2^{n-1}\times\frac{\pi}{2^{n}}\right) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\pi}{2} = \frac{\pi}{2} 
\end{align*}
Hence the proposed limit is given by
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n - 1}\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2^{n}}\right)} = \frac{2}{\pi}
\end{align*}
Hopefully this helps!

If you are able to solve the second proposed multiple choice, then the first would be the same principle. So let's consider the second question (with $n \to \infty$) and simplify the limiting quantity,
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}  \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^3}\right)\dots\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n-1}}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^n}\right) 
$$
$$ A = \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^3}\right)\dots\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n-1}}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^n}\right)$$
Using $\sin(2x) = 2\sin(x)\cos(x)$,
$$ A = \cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2^2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^3}\right)\dots\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n-1}}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^n}\right)\dfrac{2\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2^n}\right)}{2\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2^n}\right)}$$
$$ A = \cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2^2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^3}\right)\dots\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n-2}}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n-1}}\right)\dfrac{\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2^{n-1}}\right)}{2\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2^n}\right)}$$
$$ A = \cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2^2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^3}\right)\dots\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n-2}}\right)\dfrac{\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2^{n-2}}\right)}{2^2\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2^n}\right)}$$
$$\implies A = \dfrac{\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)}{2^{n-1}\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2^n}\right)}=\dfrac{1}{2^{n-1}\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2^n}\right)}$$
Best way to tackle this is using the above-mention procedure or using the L'hopital's rule,
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} 2^n\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2^n}\right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2^n}\right)}{\dfrac{1}{2^n}}=\pi\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2^n}\right) = \pi$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n - 1}\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2^{n}}\right)} = \frac{2}{\pi}$$

According to this question we have to evaluate $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{2}}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{3}}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{4}}\right)....\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n-1}}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n}}\right)$$
I appreciate Atila's and $\pi$ie's answers and I want to explain the answers in detail.
The only thing which you should keep in mind is $$\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$$
To evaluate this given limit I will multiply the numerator and denominator by $2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n}}\right)$
Let $$L=\lim_{n\to \infty}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{2}}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{3}}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{4}}\right)....\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n-1}}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n}}\right)$$
$\implies L=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n}}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{2}}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{3}}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{4}}\right)....\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n-1}}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n}}\right)}{2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n}}\right)}$
Note :
$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n-1}}\right)=2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n}}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n}}\right)$
Therefore I will multiply $2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n}}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n}}\right)$ first in the numerator.
$\implies L=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{2}}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{3}}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{4}}\right)....\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n-1}}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n-1}}\right)}{2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n}}\right)}$
Again I will multiply the numerator and denominator by $2$
$\implies L=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{2\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{2}}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{3}}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{4}}\right)....\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n-1}}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n-1}}\right)}{2^{2}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n}}\right)}$
Now
$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n-2}}\right)=2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n-1}}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n-1}}\right)$
$\implies L=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{2}}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{3}}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{4}}\right)....\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n-2}}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n-2}}\right)}{2^{2}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n}}\right)}$
Again you have to multiply the numerator and denominator by $2$ and again you have to break $2\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n-2}}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n-2}}\right)$ in the numerator and the denominator will become $2^{3}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n}}\right)$
Repeat this process till you reach the numerator to be $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$
Finally your limit will simplify to $$L=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{2^{n-1}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n}}\right)}$$
Now let's evaluate the limit
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}2^{n-1}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n}}\right)$$
Let $\lim_{n\to \infty}2^{n-1}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n}}\right)$
be $L_{1}$
$L_{1}$ can be re-written as
$$L_{1}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{2}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n}}\right)}{\frac{1}{2^{n}}}$$
$$\implies L_{1}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n}}\right)}{\frac{\pi}{2^{n}}}$$
Note :
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n}}\right)}{\frac{\pi}{2^{n}}}=1$$
$$\implies L_{1}=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
Therefore finally at last we are getting $$L=\frac{2}{\pi}$$
